# Transform an array with attributes into a list

Tags: javascript, json

I am working with a graphics library and it is very bad to manipulate the data coming from the API. The problem is that the chart lib does not accept the data format that the api I am using returns.

API response

```
const data = [
  {
      "house01": {
        "free": 6
      },
      "house02": {
        "free": 2
      },
      "house03": {
        "free": 1
      },
  }
]
```

Expected (UPDATED)

```
const data = [
          {
            "label": "house01"
            "free": 6
          },
          {
            "label": "house02"
            "free": 2
          },
          {
            "label": "house03"
            "free": 1
          },
    ]
```

Comment: By "list," do you mean "delimited string"? Or something else?
Javascript doesn't have a native List object.

Comment: List like array. What I would like to understand is how to turn the 'API response' into 'expected'

Comment: The expected data does not look like a valid json object, are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: Oh sorry, I fixed the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```js
const data = [
  {
    house01: {
      free: 6
    },
    house02: {
      free: 2
    },
    house03: {
      free: 1
    }
  }
];

const expectedData = Object.entries(data[0]).map(d => ({
  label: d[0],
  free: d[1].free
}));

console.log(expectedData)

const data2 = {
  house01: { free: 6 },
  house02: { free: 2 },
  house03: { free: 1 }
};

const expectedData2 = Object.entries(data2).map(d => ({
  label: d[0],
  free: d[1].free
}));

console.log(expectedData2);
```

Comment: Exactly! I have a doubt, because when I remove the first [] from data it returns an error in the map () function? Can you give me an example.?

Comment: Not totally sure what you mean. Can you show me the code?

Comment: Sure! In the answer you put you put you used const data = const data = [
   {
     house01: {
       free: 6
     },
     house02: {
       free: 2
     },
     house03: {
       free: 1
     }
   }
];


I would like to know how the code would look if the data were like this:

const data =
   {
     house01: {
       free: 6
     },
     house02: {
       free: 2
     },
     house03: {
       free: 1
     }
   };

Comment: Gotcha. I edited the snippet to include that scenario. In that case, you just remove the [0] on the data[0], because the data is no longer wrapped in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
  "house01": {
    "free": 6
  },
  "house02": {
    "free": 2
  },
  "house03": {
    "free": 1
  },
}]
final = [];
temp = {};
Object.entries(data[0]).forEach(student => {
  temp.label = student[0];
  Object.entries(student[1]).forEach(student1 => {
    temp[student1[0]] = student1[1];
  })
  final.push(temp);
});
console.log(final);
```